# C Program returns unexpected output

Tags: c, loops, substring, c-strings, function-definition

This code is supposed to determine if a word is present in a sentence or not. I tried with the input sen:"my name is", search:"name", but it displays not found. Please help me. Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
bool s(char *sen, char *search) {
    int k=1, i=0;
    while (*sen!='\0') {
        if (k==1 || *(sen-1)==' ') {
            if (*sen==search[i]) {
                i++;
                if (i==strlen(search) && (*(sen+1)==' ' || *(sen+1)=='\0')) return true;
            }
            else i=0;
        }
        k=0;
        sen++;
    }
    return false;
}
void main() {
    char sen[100], search[20];
    fgets(sen, 100, stdin);
    scanf("%s", search);
    if (s(sen, search)) printf("Found");
    else printf("Not found");
}
```

Comment: I suggest using the debugger, or, if you don't know how to do that, just add some `printf` statements to your code to see if the code works the way you think it does.

Comment: You're only testing one character of the match for each loop iteration. For the first character in your search word you probably enter the outer `if` appropriately, but then you increment `sen` and then `*(sen-1)==' '` will no longer be true for that word.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

take a closer look at:
`if (k==1 || *(sen-1)==' ') {`
i'm thinking this is supposed to check for the beginning of a word right ?
if the check ever fails this will only be true once. For the beginning of the word
try this instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
bool s(char *sen, char *search) {
    int k=1, i=0;
    while (*sen!='\0') {
        if (k==1 || *(sen-1)==' ') { 
           if (*sen==search[i]) {
                k = 1;
                i++;
                if (i==strlen(search) && (*(sen+1)==' ' || *(sen+1)=='\0' || *(sen+1)=='\n')) return true;
            }
            else{ 
               i=0;
               k=0;
            }
        }
        sen++;
    }
    return false;
}
void main() {
    char sen[100], search[20];
    fgets(sen, 100, stdin);
    scanf("%s", search);
    if (s(sen, search)) printf("Found");
    else printf("Not found");
}
```

k will now only be set to 0 if the beginning doesn't match, and after the beginning was matched it will be set to 1. I'm assuming that's what k was for here.

Also, your first String is "terminated" using the Enter key, so they last Symbol will not be  a '\0' but a '\n' for the new line operation:  `if (i==strlen(search) && (*(sen+1)==' ' || *(sen+1)=='\0' || *(sen+1)=='\n')) return true;`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to simultaneously (a) iterate over the string, testing each character if it is the start of a word (`k==1 || *(sen-1)==' '`), and (b) testing each character to see if it is equal to the `i`-th letter of the search word. These two goals are in conflict, because the second character of the word will never satisfy the first test (it won't be the start of a word). You should reset `i` when you find a word start, but check every character, not just the characters that start words.

Answer (score 0):

For starters according to the C Standard the function `main` without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

The parameters of the function `s` should be declared with qualifier `const` like

```
bool s( const char *sen, const char *search );
```

because passed strings are not changed within the function.

The function `fgets` can append to the entered string the new line character `'\n'` that you should remove from the string.

After the if statement

```
    if (k==1 || *(sen-1)==' ') {
        if (*sen==search[i]) {
            i++;
            if (i==strlen(search) && (*(sen+1)==' ' || *(sen+1)=='\0')) return true;
        }
        else i=0;
    }
```

the variable `k` is set to `0`

```
    k=0;
```

So the if statement will be executed only for the first one character of the string pointed to by the pointer `search` that coincides with a character in the start of a word in the string `sen`.

The function would look much simpler if to use standard C function `strstr`.  For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>

bool s( const char *sen, const char *search ) 
{
    bool found = false;
    size_t n = strlen( search );

    for ( const char *p = sen; !found && ( p = strstr( p, search ) ) != NULL; p += n )
    {
        found = ( p == sen || isblank( ( unsigned char )p[-1] ) ) &&
                ( p[n] == '\0' || isblank( ( unsigned char )p[n] ) );
    }

    return found;
}    

int main( void ) 
{
    char sen[100], search[20];

    fgets( sen, sizeof( sen ), stdin );
    sen[ strcspn( sen, "\n" ) ] = '\0';

    scanf( "%19s", search );

    if ( s( sen, search ) ) puts( "Found" );
    else puts( "Not found" );
}
```

The program output might look like

```
my name is Dhruv
name
Found
```

Comment: If `strstr()` can be used then why all those clutter needed in `s()` function? Isn't the one statement in `s()` would be sufficient - `return (strstr (sen, search) != NULL);`?

Comment: @H.S. He is searching a word that is separated by spaces. He is not searching a sub-word.